# Raising another WebBrowser DocumentCompleted()

Tags: c#, browser

It appears that the `WebBrowser_DocumentCompleted()` event is not very adequate sometimes, and for me this has been the case.  I am creating several reports web pages for automation checks (currently 5), and this event runs very soon, once, for each of these pages.  If the page isn't finished, I am wondering what the best approach is to get `DocumentCompleted()` to continue to run.

I've tried checking the ReadyState and URL to see if they match in my `automationExec()` function, and this has been worthless, ReadyState is Complete and the URLs match.  That hasn't been a problem, though, I can just check the existence of the footer tag on the page, so `ReadyState` and the `WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs.Url` do not need to be covered.

```
private void openReport(UnitTestType unitTest)
{
  BrowserPopup testBrowser = new BrowserPopup();
  WebBrowser reportBrowser = new WebBrowser();
  ...
  reportBrowser.DocumentCompleted += new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(automationExec);
  testBrowser.CreateWindow(reportBrowser, "QA Automation", unitTest.hash); //creates browser window
}

private void automationExec(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
  WebBrowser reportBrowser = (WebBrowser)sender;

  //footer, version tag
  if (reportBrowser.Document.Body.FirstChild.NextSibling.NextSibling.FirstChild.FirstChild.FirstChild.NextSibling == null)
  {
    reportBrowser.DocumentCompleted += new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(automationExec);
    //i'm not sure how to re-raise DocumentCompleted event now that it has occured
    return;
  }

  //report is complete, perform automation tests
}
```

Comment: "event is not very adequate" is not very clear explanation of the problem. Is your problem with pages that they render content asynchronously (i.e. "sometime after document complete")?

Comment: The problem is that DocumentCompleted() event executes before the page is complete.  I need to have the page completely finished, or data is missing when I run my automated tests on the XHTML.  I have heard that the DocumentCompleted() event is executed once for each frame, or it might be executed when other technology is involved like JavaScript. And there is JavaScript on these report pages I'm working with... I haven't tried DocumentCompleted() with straight HTML and nothing else, maybe it works correctly in that case, waiting to execute until the page is actually finished.

Comment: Javascript is the problem here, it runs *after* the DocumentCompleted event fires.  There is no way to find out what it is doing or when it is "complete".  Mostly because it is never actually complete, additional JS runs due to DOM events.  You can only poll with a timer to observe DOM changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't "replay" document complete event. Feels like your page is actually using some JavaScript to do rendering and is not really "complete" from your point of view when browser is done loading HTML/scripts/images. This is quite common for modern pages.

Periodically checking for something you expect to be on the page (i.e. similar to check you already have) may be the easiest option in this case.